# What does the use of a double em dash signifiy?

Tags: meaning, dashes, em-dashes

When watching *The Man who Laughs* (1928), at 40:14 the line, also pictured below, "Hey — — we saw her first!" appears.

[image]

What does the use of a double em-dash signify here?

Comment: I would presume that the double-line presents a pause for emphasis.

Comment: It seems to be a non-standard usage, although it's common to see shorter dashes combined to give a longer dash when the right symbol is not available. (Multiple em dashes can be used to indicate redaction, but that's not happening here.) https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html

Comment: Don't confuse the spoken word with the best written word. Titles and subtitles show what characters said, but what people say can be, um, er, say, a mess, and still understandable.

Comment: @John Go-Soco Or perhaps a pretty long pause to collect oneself while thinking of a suitable response (verbal or non-verbal?). But two sentences wouldn't work as well. //  Representing interactions in the written word is difficult at the best of times.

Answer (score 2):

This is really only a partial answer; but I can say empirically say, from [a Google image search for "intertitle"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=intertitle) (the word for these word-signs-in-silent movies), that this was a common convention in intertitles. As to why, I can't do more than conjecture; one would need documentation of what the intertitle writers were thinking, or how audiences then understood it. Perhaps a historian of punctuation will show up to fill in that part of the answer. My guesses would be to make a longer pause to more closely mimic how the line would be spoken or narrated, differentiating a "normal" pause (one dash) from a "dramatic" pause (two dashes); or to ensure the viewers see the dash on less-than-perfect early projection machinery; or perhaps just a convention that caught on.

For anyone with ProQuest (or TandF) access, there's [this academic article on intertitle conventions](https://search.proquest.com/openview/5be7f5ee6cefacf0b81e9ab4a9292048/), might have more.

Selected examples:

[There's this Paris 1920s video (no screenshot here) with multiple uses of multi-dashes, some double, some triple](https://dcairns.wordpress.com/2009/12/27/the-christmas-sunday-intertitle/).

From Dracula (1931):

[image: From Dracula (1931)][Source](https://dcairns.wordpress.com/2009/12/27/the-christmas-sunday-intertitle/)

From The Navigator (1924):

[image: From The Navigator (1924)][Source (lots of spammy pop-ups, be forewarned)](https://www.tumbral.com/tag/intertitle)